# Lets Encrypt ACME2 Challenge NameCheap Personal DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, certificate, domain-name, namecheap

I'm trying to get a wildcard certificate, but running into the issue that I use Namecheap as a registrar, and for API access I need to spend more money than I'm willing to, so I'm looking for alternative solutions.

One of the [supported DNS Servers](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#dns-plugins) is LuaDNS, which looks provide what I need. Namecheap supports a 'Personal DNS' option, explained [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/768/10/how-do-i-register-personal-nameservers-for-my-domain).
Can I register ns1.luadns.net as a personal DNS, and will this, in combination with the luaDNS certbot plugin, solve my wildcard certificate issue?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you've pretty much got a handle on it. The terminology is a bit confusing, but you basically need to tell NameCheap that your domain's authoritative nameservers are `ns1-4.luadns.net`. This would also work the same way with any other DNS provider (there are a ton out there).

[image: NameCheap Custom DNS settings]

Then you add your zone over on the LuaDns site, generate your API key and such and you're good to go.

It may take a while for the NS record changes to propagate out over the Internet and you don't want to try and get your cert until they do. You can run dig/nslookup queries against your ISP DNS servers (or a public resolver like Google's 8.8.8.8). But there are also websites that can check a bunch for you like this:

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/example.com